# iOS: Tracking downloads in app for caching

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, download

I'm working on an iOS app that grabs data (3D models) from a server and displays them to the user. I'm now looking to implement a system that I can use to track the models I've downloaded (the file name and its corresponding revision ID), so that I don't need to download the same file again needlessly. I was thinking about using NSUserDefaults for this, storing the filename and revision date, but I wonder if there's a better way. Any suggestions on ways I can do this?

Comment: You could create and maintain an object that acts as a memory for what has been downloaded and when.  The object could be implemented in such a way that either the local data is served if it is available or a download is triggered if the data is older than a certain point or not available at all.  While you could store something like this in NSUserDefaults, you would probably want to use something more robust like CoreData (where you could probably store the binary data of the downloaded objects as well).

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the response. What if I needed to store it between sessions though?

Comment: Glad to help.  Both persist across sessions.  I should note again that any significant amount of data to be stored like you are talking about is more robustly solved using CoreData.